# How to check if a LatLng point lies inside a polygon on the geojson layer on google maps android

Tags: java, android, geojson, google-maps-android-api-2

Currently, I am working on a location-based project. In this project I've added a GeoJsonLayer as below: [image]

As can be seen in the image, the red marker is inside a box. Is there any way to check if the marker is inside a box (polygon) or not on google maps?

Inside the onMapReady() function I have added the GeoJson layer as follow:
`

```
try {
    GeoJsonLayer layer = new GeoJsonLayer(mMap, R.raw.gokulpeth_area, MapsActivity.this);
    layer.getDefaultPolygonStyle().setStrokeColor(Color.WHITE);
    layer.addLayerToMap();
} catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

`
Please help me to achieve the task.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Ray-casting algorithm](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Ray-casting_algorithm#Java)

Comment: @RickyMo I guess it's not applicable here because I could not get the bounds of the polygon where the LatLng/maker is placed. The marker is showing the current location of the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`containsLocation(double latitude, double longitude, java.util.List<LatLng> polygon, boolean geodesic)`](https://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html#containsLocation-double-double-java.util.List-boolean-) method from [Maps SDK for Android Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility):

> public static boolean containsLocation(double latitude,
> double longitude,
> java.util.List polygon,
> boolean geodesic)
>
> Computes whether the given point lies inside the specified polygon.
> The polygon is always considered closed, regardless of whether the
> last point equals the first or not. Inside is defined as not
> containing the South Pole -- the South Pole is always outside. The
> polygon is formed of great ci rcle segments if geodesic is true, and of rhumb
> (loxodromic) segments otherwise.